# Can I change the source code of a basic Android application?

Tags: applications

I already know how to build applications using Android Studio.

I would like to know if there is a way to access and modify the source code of an Android application. For instance, can I add some features in the Calculator modifying its source code ?

Comment: Is this question better suited for Stack Overflow ?

Comment: Last time I checked, Android standard apps that are part of AOSP usually don't use Android Studio for building, instead they are built by the scripts that also build the operating system. Thus getting and building them is not that simple.